# Do I have to recheck my luggage, pass security and get a visa for a connection flight in London?

Tags: london, lhr, connecting-flights, qatar-airways, air-canada

I'm traveling from Toronto, Canada to India via Connections in London Heathrow & Kuwait in an Indian Passport.

- **Canada to London (Terminal 2)** 6.55 hr layover - **Air Canada**
- **London(Terminal 4) to Kuwait(Terminal 4)**  6.10 hr layover - **Qatar Airways**
- Kuwait(Terminal M) to India 4.5 hr layover  - Qatar Airways

My doubts are:

1. Do I need a Visa either in London or Kuwait?
2. Does Air Canada do the baggage transfer in London to my connecting flight?
3. Someone also told me that to transfer from terminal 2-4 in London, we need to go out of the airport and I believe we need a Visa for that. But my travels is saying it is not required.

All of these bookings are on a single ticket booked via flight center. I've contacted the airlines and flight center but didn't get a confident reply. I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: This is really four separate questions. At least three of them already have answers on the site: [Transit visa for UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34106/11491) [Transit visa for Kuwait?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/96677/11491) [Airside transit at Heathrow?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/106867/11491).

Answer (score 3):

Since your flights are on a single ticket, the airline will almost certainly transfer your bags. For peace of mind, you can confirm this when you check in  ask the check-in agent if your bags are checked through to your final destination or if you'll need to pick them up in London and/or Kuwait.